# Giving parameters a metatag for reflection

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to flag a parameter in such a way that I can read the tag via reflection.  The reason I want to do this is because I am creating business layer objects that map to a database and I want to flag certain parameters as 'read-only', such as `uniqueidentifier` fields that are being generated in the database.

I am already iterating through the properties for filling the parameters.  This is a snippet of how I'm assigning values...

```
foreach (var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   switch (prop.PropertyType.Name)
   {
      case "Int32":
          int tmpInt = -1;
          if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(rowFromDatabase[prop.Name]) && int.TryParse(rowFromDatabase[prop.Name].ToString(), out tmpInt))
          {
             prop.SetValue(sender, tmpInt);
          }
          break;
      case "Boolean":
          bool tmpBool = false;
          if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(rowFromDatabase[prop.Name]) && bool.TryParse(rowFromDatabase[prop.Name].ToString(), out tmpBool))
          {
             prop.SetValue(sender, tmpBool);
          }
          break;
          ..............
          continued...
          ..............
   }
}
```

I want to be able to access some kind of metadata on a parameter that is accessible via the `prop` variable shown above where I can specify some kind of extra information.  How can I do this?

EDIT:  I'd like to set the metadata like this

```
[CustomTag]
public Guid ID { get; set; }
```

Comment: You can create a custom attribute and apply that to your properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x6cd29c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The edit made it less clear. Do you want it for parameters, arguments or for properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend the class `System.Attribute` then decorate your properties with your custom attributes.

For example:

```
public class ReadOnlyAttribute : System.Attribute
{
}
```

or

```
public class DbColumnInfoAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public string ColumnName {get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }

    public DbColumnInfoAttribute( string name, bool req){
       ColumnName = name;
       Required = req;
    }
}
```

Then use them:

```
public class YourClass
{

   [ReadOnly]
   [DbColumnInfo( "User_Name", true)]
   public string UserName { get; set; }

}
```

To read them via Reflection:

```
var listOfAttrib = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true);
```

#### I would recommend that ALL of your attribute classes extend a common class so you can get all custom properties without having to know the exact attribute you're looking for otherwise you'll end up having to fire multiple GetCustomAttributes

Comment: How would you access those attributes?

Comment: nice, I figured this functionality was built-in already, just had never used it.